# Cannot read file from disk

Tags: vb.net, excel

When I upload an excel file from my vb app, it's fine for the first time. If I try it a second time I am having this error: **The process cannot access the file (path) because it is bein used by another process**.  Below is my code:

```
    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

    fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
    fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    fd.Filter = "All files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    fd.FilterIndex = 2
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True
    Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing

    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

        Try
            myStream = fd.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(fd.FileName)
                worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

                TextBox1.Text = worksheet.Cells(1, 7).Value
                TextBox2.Text = worksheet.Cells(2, 7).Value
                TextBox3.Text = worksheet.Cells(3, 7).Value

                l1.Text = worksheet.Cells(2, 1).Value * 10
                w1.Text = worksheet.Cells(2, 2).Value * 10
                q1.Text = worksheet.Cells(2, 3).Value
                p1.Text = worksheet.Cells(2, 4).Value..........

                Dim Values(119, 3) As String
                Values(0, 0) = l1.Text
                Values(0, 1) = w1.Text
                Values(0, 2) = q1.Text
                Values(0, 3) = p1.Text.........

                Dim add As Integer = 0
                Dim pressing As Integer = 0

                If adding.Text = "50" Or adding.Text = "" Then
                    add = 50
                Else
                    add = Convert.ToInt16(adding.Text)
                End If

                If press.Text = "20" Or press.Text = "" Then
                    pressing = 20
                Else
                    pressing = Convert.ToInt16(press.Text)
                End If

                Dim l As Integer
                Dim w As Integer
                Dim machinearea As Integer

                Dim connetionString As String
                Dim cnn As SqlConnection
                connetionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=lumber;User ID=sa;Password=sasql"
                cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
                Dim cmd As SqlCommand
                Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
                Dim query As String

                query = "SELECT length,width from marea"
                cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cnn)
                cnn.Open()
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If myreader.Read() Then
                    l = myreader.Item("length")
                    w = myreader.Item("width")
                End If
                cnn.Close()

                machinearea = l * w

                Dim allTextBoxes2 = From txt In Me.Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
           Order By txt.TabIndex
                Dim txtList2 = allTextBoxes2.ToList()

                For i As Int32 = 0 To txtList2.Count - 1
                    Dim thisTxt = txtList2(i)
                    Dim nextIndex = If(i + 1 >= txtList2.Count, 0, i + 1)
                    Dim prevIndex = If(i - 1 < 0, txtList2.Count - 1, i - 1)
                    Dim nextTxt = txtList2(nextIndex)
                    Dim prevTxt = txtList2(prevIndex)
                    Dim testInt As Integer = 0

                    If thisTxt.Text = "0" Then
                        thisTxt.Clear()
                    End If

                Next

                Dim allTextBoxes = From txt In Me.Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                              Order By txt.TabIndex
                Dim txtList = allTextBoxes.ToList()


                For i As Int32 = 0 To txtList.Count - 1
                    Dim thisTxt = txtList(i)
                    For j = 2 To -1
                        For k = 1 To 4
                            thisTxt.Text = worksheet.Cells(i + j, k).Value
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            End If

        Catch Ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)

        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open.
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear.  You have another process (application) that has a lock on the file which is preventing your program for accessing it.  Find out what the process is and kill it, and then run your app again.

Comment: Actually, the "other process" is likely yourself.  You need to close the workbook that you opened, before you try to open it again.

Comment: I cannot close the application. I need to upload several times and the process is "EXCEL.EXE". If I kill it it will kill all opened excel files.

Comment: I didn't say to kill the Application, I said to *close the Workbook*.  The Workbook class has a Close method.  Use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try
            myStream = fd.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(fd.FileName, ReadOnly:=True, Notify:=False)
                worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
```

...

```
    Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open.
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.Close()
            End If
            If (workbook IsNot Nothing) Then
                workbook.Close()
            End If
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the application is closed and no process is running or it will give you that error.